# Jetpack Compose - how to deal with different screen sizes?

Tags: android, apk, android-jetpack-compose, android-resources, dpi

I have started to work with Jetpack Compose, and while there some great features that it provides to us, I still have some doubt on whether this new ui toolkit is more performant and makes more sense than the traditional Android ui toolkit with xmls.

Considering you are building an app and want to support screens of different sizes and pixel densities, with the **xml** you would create different `dimens.xml`, for example:

```
hdpi/dimens.xml
xxhdpi/dimens.xml
sw720dp/dimens.xml
....
```

Finally, each device would get only the values that apply for its configuration resulting in a smaller bundle to install.

As per Jetpack Compose, the approach to this situation seems to be different. Instead of taking advantage of the Android app bundle feature that would make the final installable file smaller in size, with Compose most the solutions that I have seen tend to differentiate the resources for different screen sizes in `@Composable` level. Which means the final installable file will hold even the values that the device will not need. The solution is something like this, first you create the class with default values:

`class Dimensions`

then you extend this to `override` the resources for different screen sizes or densities

`val smallDimensions = Dimensions`

`val sw360Dimensions = Dimensions`

etc.

and to get the values for each size in your `@Composable` fun you do:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val dimensions = if (configuration.screenWidthDp <= 360) smallDimensions else sw360Dimensions
```

*Given the cons of this approach, do you think is better to still keep the `dimens` and other resources in `xml` file while using compose, and instead of manually figuring out what values the device needs let the Android do it for you?*

If we still keep the `dimens` in xml, we can refer to them as:

```
dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.leftMargin)
```

The bundle would be smaller (although not something significant), and yet we are compose friendly.

References:

[Jetpack Compose: What is the best way to support all screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905110/jetpack-compose-what-is-the-best-way-to-support-all-screen-sizes)

https://proandroiddev.com/supporting-different-screen-sizes-on-android-with-jetpack-compose-f215c13081bd

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVrFiogpyr8&ab_channel=Stevdza-San

Comment: I think yes, dimensions is better to keep into dimens.xml, string resources in strings.xml, but colors..i think in Colors.kt file )